# What is the name of this Android element?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

What is the name of this Android element in the front? It's look like alert or some custom theme for activity. How to make something like this?

[image: Firefox Nightly screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Bottomsheet. Learn more about it [here](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom#anatomy) and [here's](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427) how to implement it in your app.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i need.